# Clear html table row content

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to clear the content of an html table rows by using a clear button, this is the code i used:

```
<buttontype="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ClearTable(this)">
    Clear
</button>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="membersTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>BirthDate</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >

                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
    <script>
function ClearTable(btn) {
        $('#membersTable tbody tr td').val("");
        
    }
    </script>
```

But this code is not working, it doesn't clear the content of the table. Any help?

Comment: Maybe use `.html('')` instead? `.val()` is for form input value.

Comment: But .html('') deletes also the Html.EditorFor and i  want to keep it, i want to delete only the content of the cell not the EditorFor